# Searching a word dictionary in a table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

1st is **sentence** having **title** column with values.

```
my name is A.
B is my name.
I am C kind.
I am nice.
```

2nd is **name** having **val** column with values.

```
B.
C.
A.
D.
H.
```

I want to write a query which will return those **titles** which contains any **val** from **name** table. 
Also i want those **val** which are present in **title** of **sentence** table.
How can i achieve this using select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables with a `LIKE` operator.

To get all the titles that have any `val` in them:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(s.title) AS title
FROM sentence AS s
JOIN name AS n ON s.title LIKE CONCAT('%', n.val, '%');
```

To get all the vals that are in any of the titles:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(n.val) AS val
FROM sentence AS s
JOIN name AS n ON s.title LIKE CONCAT('%', n.val, '%');
```

Comment: alternatively, `join ... on locate(n.val, s.title) <> 0)`

Comment: I dont want a join between both tables i want separate results for furthur operation. i.e. i want only those titles which contains any val in one select statement and those val which are present in title in other select statement.

Comment: You still use a join to do this. Just select different columns in the two queries.

Comment: @vatsal Yes, but it will automatically convert numbers to strings if necessary.

Comment: I don't know what that means. The column contains a string, it works for that.

Comment: @vatsal What about it isn't working? It should only return the first sentence and val `A.`.

Comment: It won't return the second sentence because the value `B.` has a `.` in it, but there's no `.` after `B` in the title.

Comment: Concat function does not wok on my system is their any alternative for that + is also not woking

Comment: `CONCAT` function should work. `+` is not used for concatenation in MySQL. Are you sure you're using MySQL, not Oracle or SQL-Server?

Comment: Thanks for the solution i think the problem was with editor it is working fine now on another editor.